# detecting tap in map circle overlay always returning false

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have a map with a circle overlay and it's always returning false from the CGPathContainsPoint method.  Am I passing in the wrong tapPoint values?

```
func didTapMap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapPoint: CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(map)
    NSLog("%@,%@",tapPoint.x, tapPoint.y)

    for overlay in self.map.overlays{
        if (overlay.isKindOfClass(MKCircle))
        {
            let circle = overlay as MKCircle
            let circleRenderer:MKCircleRenderer = map.rendererForOverlay(circle) as MKCircleRenderer
            circleRenderer.invalidatePath()
            let mapCoordinateIsInCircle = CGPathContainsPoint(circleRenderer.path, nil, tapPoint, false)

            if (mapCoordinateIsInCircle == true)
            {
                NSLog("tapped in circle");
                break
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the wrong tap point values are being passed to `CGPathContainsPoint`.

The values in the overlay renderer's `path` are not in screen `CGPoint` units.
The `path` contains values that correspond to the renderer's own drawing context which is different from the screen.

You need to first convert the tap point which is a screen `CGPoint` into a point in the renderer's drawing context.

`MKOverlayRenderer` (base class of `MKCircleRenderer`) has the method `pointForMapPoint:` which can help but it takes an `MKMapPoint` (not screen `CGPoint`).

So you need to convert the screen `CGPoint` to an `MKMapPoint` and then finally to a point in the renderer's context.

To convert from screen `CGPoint` to `MKMapPoint`, you'll need to first convert it to a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` using the map view's `convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView:` and then to a `MKMapPoint` using the `MKMapPointForCoordinate` function.

Example:

```
func didTapMap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapPoint: CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(map)
    NSLog("tapPoint = %f,%f",tapPoint.x, tapPoint.y)

    //convert screen CGPoint tapPoint to CLLocationCoordinate2D...
    let tapCoordinate = map.convertPoint(tapPoint, toCoordinateFromView: map)

    //convert CLLocationCoordinate2D tapCoordinate to MKMapPoint...
    let tapMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(tapCoordinate)

    for overlay in self.map.overlays{
        if (overlay.isKindOfClass(MKCircle))
        {
            let circle = overlay as MKCircle
            let circleRenderer:MKCircleRenderer = map.rendererForOverlay(circle) as MKCircleRenderer

            //convert MKMapPoint tapMapPoint to point in renderer's context...
            let tapRendererPoint = circleRenderer.pointForMapPoint(tapMapPoint)

            circleRenderer.invalidatePath()

            let mapCoordinateIsInCircle = CGPathContainsPoint(circleRenderer.path, nil, tapRendererPoint, false)

            if (mapCoordinateIsInCircle == true)
            {
                NSLog("tapped in circle");
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

By the way, with circles, an easier way to detect taps inside them is to calculate the distance of the tap point from the center of the circle.  If the tap point distance is less than or equal to the circle's radius, then it's a tap inside the circle.

This way, you don't need to get the circle's renderer, its path, or CGPathContainsPoint.

Example:

```
func didTapMap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapPoint: CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(map)
    NSLog("tapPoint = %f,%f",tapPoint.x, tapPoint.y)

    let tapCoordinate = map.convertPoint(tapPoint, toCoordinateFromView: map)

    let tapMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(tapCoordinate)

    for overlay in self.map.overlays{
        if (overlay.isKindOfClass(MKCircle))
        {
            let circle = overlay as MKCircle

            let circleCenterMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(circle.coordinate)

            let distanceFromCircleCenter = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(circleCenterMapPoint, tapMapPoint)

            if distanceFromCircleCenter <= circle.radius {
                NSLog("tapped in circle");
                break
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: I think your suggestion "with circles, an easier way to detect taps inside them is to calculate the distance of the tap point from the center of the circle" is the relevant point. I marked it up because that solved my problem in Objective C. Ta!